# Angular2+ File Upload with ng2-file-upload - Child component keeps calling Parent Component functions

Tags: javascript, html, angular, file-upload, ng2-file-upload

I have a parent component in which I have 2 input `type="file"` elements which call the function `getFileForParent()` on file change :

```
<input type="file" (change)="getFileForParent()" />
```

And in my child component I have one :

```
<input type="file" (change)="getFileForChild()" />
```

but whenever I select a file on the child component the parents `getFileForParent` is called.
I am using `ng2-file-upload`.

**Parent ts:**

```
getFileForParent(){
    if(this.uploaderForParent.queue[0].file.type != 'application/PDF'){
        this.showError("Please select pdf files only");
        return;
    }
    this.uploaderForParent.uploadAll();
}
```

**Child ts:**

```
getFileForChild(){
    if(this.uploaderForChild.queue[0].file.type != 'application/PDF'){
        this.showError("Please select pdf files only");
        return;
    }
    this.uploaderForChild.uploadAll();
}
```

Comment: can you share your ts code

Comment: @Chellappan done.

Answer (score 2):

> Its working fine for me

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ijh23g)

**parent.component.html**

```
<h1>
    Parent Component File inputs:
</h1>

<input type="file" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploaderForParent" (change)="getFileForParent()" />
<input type="file" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploaderForParent" (change)="getFileForParent()" />


<h1>
    Child Component File inputs:
</h1>

<app-child-comopnent></app-child-comopnent>
```

**parent.component.ts:**

```
uploaderForParent: FileUploader = new FileUploader({ url: 'any' });

  getFileForParent() {
    console.log("Parent");
    console.log(this.uploaderForParent);


    if (this.uploaderForParent.queue[0].file.type != 'application/PDF') {
      alert("Please select pdf files only");
      return;
    }
    //this.uploaderForParent.uploadAll();
  }
```

**child.component.html:**

```
<input type="file" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploaderForChild" (change)="getFileForChild()" />
```

**child.component.ts:**

```
uploaderForChild: FileUploader = new FileUploader({ url: 'any' });

getFileForChild() {

    console.log("child");
    console.log(this.uploaderForChild);
    if (this.uploaderForChild.queue[0].file.type != 'application/PDF') {
      alert("Please select pdf files only");
    }
    //this.uploaderForChild.uploadAll();
  }
```